# Firebase Database - How to extract elements from a documents query?

Tags: python, database, firebase

I have a python script that is requesting data from the database through the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime

import re

global dateTimeObj
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
path = db.collection(u'users').document(u'a@a.com')
doc_ref = path.collection(u'feedback').order_by(u'time_stamp').stream()
for doc in doc_ref:
    a = u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict())
    print(a)
```

output:

```
feedback_1 => {'feedback_sub_item': 'feedback sub item', 'feedback': 'feedback message', 'record_id': '111', 'cycle_id': 'normal', 'rating': 3.5, 'time_stamp': '02/28/2020 16:15:58'}
feedback_2 => {'feedback_sub_item': 'feedback sub item', 'feedback': 'feedback message', 'record_id': '112', 'cycle_id': 'normal', 'rating': 4, 'time_stamp': '02/28/2020 16:16:52'}
```

My question is, how I can convert this message to extract the parameters from the last feedback based on the time_stamp field?

My desired output is:

```
Feedback_number = feedback_2
feedback_sub_item = feedback sub item
feedback = feedback message
record_id = 112
cycle_id = normal
rating = 4
time_stamp = 02/28/2020 16:16:52
```

thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the dictionary, you can use the split function. Then you can iterate through this dictionary with its keys.

To do this, you can use a 'for' loop to display the values contained in the dictionary.

```
# a is your last feedback
new_list = a.split("=>")
new_dict = eval(new_list[1])

print("feedback_number = ", new_list[0])    
for key in new_dict:
        print(key," = ",new_dict[key])
```

With this exemple your obtain:

```
feedback_number =  feedback_2
feedback_sub_item  =  feedback sub item
feedback  =  feedback message
record_id  =  112
cycle_id  =  normal
rating  =  4
time_stamp  =  02/28/2020 16:16:52
```

I hope that answers your question

Comment: Hi, thanks replying back. if I run the command type(a) it is giving me a string type and in this string I have all the text described in the output, I mean, it gets a dictionary structure but also get the text "feedback_1 =>" and "feedback_2 =>" in front of the dict structure. Running your code I get a TypeError: string indices must be integers. Any idea how to solve it? thnks